# HTML Web Audio, Video AutoPlay, Mute and AudioWorklets

Tags: html5-video, audio-worklet

*Objective: Display HTML 5 Video with VU Meters, (no audio to speakers) on page load without user interaction.*

I'll need to use an AudioWorklet to meter the audio from the HTML5 Video object.

AIUI, Video won't autoplay unless the "muted" flag is set, (because the user hasn't interacted with the page). If "muted" is set, will my AudioWorklet actually receive samples from the Video object?

Apologies for not showing any code or actually trying this yet, but there's a steep learning curve for me here and I'm reluctant to go down this path if I'll hit a brick wall.